# The closest ellipse to a given triangle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, triangles, conic-sections

Definition: The Hausdorff distance between two point sets is the greatest of all the distances from a point in one set to the closest point in the other set.

**Question:** Given a general triangle T, to find and characterize the ellipse E that minimizes the Hausdorff distance from T. It is not clear to me if E is unique.

Note 1: Some further questions/thoughts are recorded at https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/01/approximating-triangles-by-ellipses.html
and
https://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/01/approximating-planar-convex-sets-by-n.html

Note 2: As has been pointed out by Matt F in comments below, the special case of the ellipse being a circle is itself of nontrivial interest.

Comment: I think the right place to start is some easier questions: *What circle minimizes this distance?* This is an algebraic question, whose answer is probably a well-known triangle center. And even easier: *What radius minimizes this distance for circles around the incenter?*

Comment: Thanks! I had arrived at the question thinking about the steiner ellipses of a triangle and had overlooked the basic case of the ellipse being a circle.  The broader point that one was trying to make with this question and also in the pages linked above was that although *smallest containing x / largest contained x for a given y* (where x and y are any two different kinds of shapes) kind of problems are well studied, *closest x to a given y* (closest in terms of Hausdorff distance) is a class of questions that seems relatively unexplored.

Comment: For circles around the incenter, I think the optimal radius is $\frac12(1+\cot\frac\alpha2)$ times the inradius, where $\alpha$ is the smallest angle in the triangle.

Comment: Guess: At least in the case of the triangle-circle pair, if C is the circle that approximates (in the Hausdorff sense as in the present question) a given triangle T best, then, T *might not* be the triangle that approximates C best.