# The closest ellipse and circle to a given triangle - 2

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, conic-sections

We add a little more to [The closest ellipse to a given triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438626/the-closest-ellipse-to-a-given-triangle).

The above linked discussion used the Hausdorff distance to quantify how close two planar convex regions are.

In an earlier post - [Comparing convex planar regions of equal perimeter and area - 2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417428/comparing-convex-planar-regions-of-equal-perimeter-and-area-2) - we mentioned other measures of distance between planar convex regions C1 and C2, for ex: *the average least distance of a boundary point on C1 from a boundary point on C2*. So, one could ask (for example):

**Question:** Given a general triangle T, find that circle C (ellipse E) such that the average over boundary points of C(E) of closest distance from that point to a boundary point of T is minimized.

**Further thoughts:** If given a T, E is somehow found, then is T that triangle (or one of the triangles) that minimizes average distance from from points on E?

**Remarks:** One could also *compare* the answers to this set of questions to the ones in [The closest ellipse to a given triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438626/the-closest-ellipse-to-a-given-triangle). For example, if one is given a square and is looking for the circles closest to it, the closest circle in terms of Hausdorff distance seems slightly larger than the closest circle ito of the average least distance with both centered at the square center.
However if one starts with a triangle, it is not clear whether the two closest ellipses to it have the  same center and orientation.

Note added on Feb 18th 2923: Some further thoughts are recorded at http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/02/spectrums-of-convex-regions-of-same.html

Comment: Have you determined this circle for any non-trivial examples?

Comment: I have no good attack on these questions so recorded them here.